# Dump of geo data with igaster/laravel_cities is not valid

Tags: laravel, geolocation

In laravel app with use of igaster/laravel_cities 1.3.12 (which gets data from https://download.geonames.or site) I have make dump
and checking my region I see that it does not have all parent_id set :

[image]

I need
a) to select country
b) regions("Oblast") of the selected country above
d) Next Region("Rajon") or city of the region selected above

But without parent_id set I can not set this tree

if there a way to fix it ? Or have I use other source of data?
Now I need to set locations for Ukraine and Spain and USA, but later I will need to add other countries...